# how do display an image after button is clicked 5 times

Tags: javascript

Is there a javascript that would allow me to display a button that the user clicks to load any  of 5 images. Then after the button is click "X" number of times Hello World appears below the button

I have been able to find scripts that will count the number of times a button is clicked, but nothing that results in an action after a certain number of clicks.

Any recommendations are appreciated.

Comment: post some codes what you've tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up your code as follows:

```
<style type="text/css">
  #hello {
    display: none;
  }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var numClicks = 0;
  var x = 5;
  function action() {
    numClicks++;
    if (numClicks == x) {
      //do something here
      //get hello div and make it visible
      var hello = document.getElementById("hello");
      hello.style.display = 'block';
    }
  }
</script>    
<button type="button" onclick="action()">a button</button>
<div id="hello">Hello World!</div>
```